# FB.login in modal doesn't open popup

Tags: facebook, cordova, ionic-framework, popup, fbloginview

we are using social now on the app, but we're encountering problems in the facebook modal.

In nutshell, a user browses to a facebook group and with a custom button, we open an URL that contains our app.

Problem consist in the fact that:

1. if the URL is opened (due to the platform specification or version) in a full-screen browser when user click "FACEBOOK LOGIN" a login modal is shown, but
2. if the URL is opened (as in some iOS versions) in the FB modal, no one modal is shown and is **IMPOSSIBLE** debug that one due to the fact that belogs to the facebook app (in this case -- not debugable)

Does someone have the same problem ??

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I attach also the code function:

```
function fbLogin() {
    $$Loader.start();

    Service.getFBAppID().then(
        function(res) {
        if (res) {
            $$FBAuthz.init(res).then(function() {

            // Try to show to the user FB login mask
            FB.login(function(res) {
                if (res.authResponse) {
                var token = res.authResponse.accessToken;
                $log.debug("INTRO: FB credentials valid. Fetching informations");

                // User authenticated successfully on FB
                // Try now to authenticate user into GoWeb system
                $$User.login(null, null, {
                    accessToken: res.authResponse.accessToken
                }).then(
                    function(res) {
                    $log.debug("INTRO: User will be redirect to state requested");

                    // User FB account exist and he's now authenticated into system
                    // Redirecting user to requested page
                    $state.go("home");
                    }, function(err) {
                    $log.debug("ERROR INTRO: FB user credentials appear to be not associate with any user in the system");

                    // System didn't recognize FB credentials inside system
                    // Try to ask to the user if has a valid app account
                    $state.go("check_user_account", {
                        accessToken: res.authResponse.accessToken
                    });
                    }
                );
                } else {
                $log.debug('INTRO: User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                $$Loader.stop();
                }
            }, function() {
                $log.debug("INTRO: User refused to continue with login process");
                $$Loader.stop();
            });
            }, function(err) {
            $log.debug("ERROR INTRO: An error ocurred during FB initialization");
            $$Loader.stop();
            });
        } else {
            // If widget is not requested by an external platform treat case normally
            $$Loader.stop();
        }
        });
    }
```

Function is binded by controller (below piece)

```
 vm.fbLogin = fbLogin;
```

And used in HTML like belo

```
<gbo-row gbo-if-widget
         gbo-if
         condition-value="true"
         condition-operator-value="'=='"
         condition-provider="TenantService"
         condition-provider-field="data.fbEnabled"
         condition-provider-async-function="isActive">
  <gbo-button gbo-effect
              gbo-effect-delay="500"
              on-click="vm.fbLogin()"
              label="fb_login_action"
              gbo-effect-name="fadeBottomTop"
              classes-inner-button="col s12 m12 l12 blue"
              classes="hidden white-text col s8 offset-s2 m4 offset-m4 l2 offset-l5">
  </gbo-button>
</gbo-row>
```

Comment: please add the relevant code or an example we can test

Comment: Calling that thing a “browser” is a joke, Facebook is basically not giving a crap that they break standard web functionality for a large percentage of users with that atrocity. This is likely not a problem specific to “social now” (whatever that is), but basically anything that uses the client-side login flow, that is based on using a popup window, will fail in that scenario AFAIK. […]

Comment: […] If switching to the server-side login flow (that uses redirects in the existing window instance, instead of popups) is not an option, then I guess the best thing you can do is try to recognize this piece of s…oftware based on its user agent, and show a message to these users, that they should please open the page in a real browser instead.

Comment: @luschn thanks for responding, I add the function code related to the FB button. Simon

Comment: @misorude you're saying that in a modal opened by whatever facebook "call to action", won't fail in opening popups? (because this is the scenario that is now failing)

Comment: No, I’m saying that as far as I know, the in-app browser can not handle _real_ popups (window.open) at all, and that is what FB.login is using.

Comment: yeah! that's the problem. So my approach was used intents (with which one we can open a real browser in order to be able to show properly popups): but the problem is related to the SAFARI browser, that doesn't expose any F....k API to trigger a new page opening.